# How can I visualize what happens during loss.backward()?

Tags: pytorch, backpropagation

I am confident in my understanding of the forward pass of my model, how can I control its backward pass?

This is not a theoretical question about what back-propagation is. The question is a practical one, about whether or not there are tools suited to visualize/track/control what happens during back-propagation.

Ideally, this tool would allow to visualize the structure of the computational graph of the model (a graph of the model's operations), its inputs and its trainable parameters.

Now, I do:

```
loss.backward()
```

and I would like to visualize what happens in that step.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is still off-topic, as you are asking for a recommendation of a tool or software. I think you might be better off looking for some tools on a different site. AFAIK, there also should be already some questions out there that address this issue.

Comment: Ok. So should I delete it?

I don't know a priori that there isn't a way to answer my question using PyTorch only. It would not seem off-topic to me if someone answered the question in that way.

Also, it is actually not straightforward to find answers "out there" on that question.

Comment: This question does not belong here but I will still try to address it. - You can use torchviz for visualization https://github.com/szagoruyko/pytorchviz
- To understand back-propagation if you want some academic paper you can see https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.05767
- If you want more code like examples you can check autograd (https://github.com/hips/autograd). pytorch's autograd is motivated by this.
- A tutorial version of autograd is implemented here (https://github.com/mattjj/autodidact).

Answer (score 10):

There has been been already mention of `pytorchviz` which lets you visualize the graph.

Here is a small example that might help you to understand how `pytorchviz` does trace the graph using the `grad_fn`:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
d = 5
x = torch.rand(d, requires_grad=True)
print('Tensor x:', x)
y = torch.ones(d, requires_grad=True)
print('Tensor y:', y)
loss = torch.sum(x*y)*3

del x
print()
print('Tracing back tensors:')
def getBack(var_grad_fn):
    print(var_grad_fn)
    for n in var_grad_fn.next_functions:
        if n[0]:
            try:
                tensor = getattr(n[0], 'variable')
                print(n[0])
                print('Tensor with grad found:', tensor)
                print(' - gradient:', tensor.grad)
                print()
            except AttributeError as e:
                getBack(n[0])

loss.backward()
getBack(loss.grad_fn)
```

*Output:*

```py
Tensor x: tensor([0.0042, 0.5376, 0.7436, 0.2737, 0.4848], requires_grad=True)
Tensor y: tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], requires_grad=True)

Tracing back tensors:
<MulBackward object at 0x1201bada0>
<SumBackward0 object at 0x1201bacf8>
<ThMulBackward object at 0x1201bae48>
<AccumulateGrad object at 0x1201badd8>
Tensor with grad found: tensor([0.0042, 0.5376, 0.7436, 0.2737, 0.4848], requires_grad=True)
 - gradient: tensor([3., 3., 3., 3., 3.])

<AccumulateGrad object at 0x1201bad68>
Tensor with grad found: tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], requires_grad=True)
 - gradient: tensor([0.0125, 1.6129, 2.2307, 0.8211, 1.4543])
```

Further you should definately take a look into how *autograd functions* (that are used by the `backward()`-function) are actually work !
Here is a tutorial from the pytorch site with an easy and short example:

***[PyTorch: Defining New autograd Functions](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/examples_autograd/two_layer_net_custom_function.html)***

Hope this helps a bit!